# Tomcat status 404 spring boot when calling controller method from using window.location from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-boot, tomcat

[Tomcat error when calling controller function from window.location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jSCr.png)

I am calling below function when textbox value is changed:
`window.location.href = window.location.protocol + "//"
                                    + window.location.host + "/server/"
                                    + $("#fqdn").val() + "/edit";`

which calls the controller method.
This works find when Run As>Spring Boot in eclipse but when running on server throws 404 not found error.

How can this be resolved?

Comment: What's your goal ?

Comment: My goal is to call a controller function on textbox value changed from javascript. Note:index page loads and works fine, 404 error occurs when I entered value in textbox which invokes changed event which in turn calls controller function.

Comment: Can you show us the JS involved ?